# Autofac.Web: Impact of having *both* PropertyInjection and AttributedInjection configured

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autofac

I've inherited some old ASP.NET Webforms code using the Autofac nuget package `Autofac.Web`. I noticed that the configuration defines *both* the `PropertyInjection` module and the `AttributedInjection` module - in contravention of the documentation [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#explicit-injection-via-attributes) which explicitly states:

> First, remove the `PropertyInjectionModule` from your web.config file and replace it with the `AttributedInjectionModule`

But the autofac entries in web.config look like this (with a similar setting in `httpModules`):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="ContainerDisposal" ... etc .../>
    <!-- Should next line be removed? -->
    <add name="PropertyInjection"  ... etc .../>
    <add name="AttributedInjection" ... etc .../>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The pages in the application typically use the `[InjectUnsetProperties]` attribute.

For the most part, the application seems to work - but there are a few odd problems that *may* be DI related. Changing the configuration to follow the documentation would obviously involve a large retesting effort - needless to say automated testing is not extensive in this old code.

I've no experience using Autofac in Webforms - can anyone explain the impact of the above misconfiguration and what, if any, problems it might cause? Also, conversely, what is the potential impact of removing the `PropertyInjection` module?

Answer (score 2):

If you have both modules in place, both will run and both will do their injection work.

The problem there is that `AttributedInjectionModule` is more restrictive - it only injects where you explicitly tell it to - whereas `PropertyInjectionModule` has a bit more general coverage - it injects always. Having both will result in the loss of control the attributes give because the `PropertyInjectionModule` will just inject everything anyway.

You also may run into issues where some dependency types are instantiated twice - once for each module injecting in the pipeline.

If you remove the `PropertyInjectionModule` then only attributed things will get injected and you'll retain the more granular control.